# How to check whether a file is locked in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsfilemanager

Is there any API to check whether a file is a locked? I am not able to find any API in the `NSFileManager` class.Let me know if there is any API to check the lock of the file.

I found the following link related to file lock

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2006/Nov/msg01399.html

I can  invoke  – isWritableFileAtPath: on file. Is there any other way to find whether a file is locked?

Comment: What sort of locking?  POSIX locking or the higher level one (that I don't know the name of)?

Comment: @trojanfoe: I am not really sure about the locking.May be it is POSIX. I locked the file using finder. I would like to check the locked files in my application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Following Code worked for me.

```
NSError * error;
NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
BOOL isLocked = [[attributes objectForKey:NSFileImmutable] boolValue];
            
if (isLocked) {
    NSLog(@"File is locked");
}
```

Comment: There's a [`NSFileImmutable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsfileimmutable?language=objc) constant that you can use rather than hard-coding the string, I'll edit that in.

Answer (score 3):

I don't really know the answer to this question as I don't know how OS X implements its locking mechanism.

It *might* use the POSIX advisory locking as documented in the `flock()` [manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/flock.2.html) and if I were you I would write a <strike>10</strike> 31-line test program in C to show what `fcntl()` ([manpage](http://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/fcntl.2.html)) thinks about the advisory lock you have made from within Finder.

Something like (untested):

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
        const char *filename = argv[i];
        int fd = open(filename, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd >= 0)
        {
            struct flock flock;
            if (fcntl(fd, F_GETLK, &flock) < 0)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to get lock info for '%s': %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
            }
            else
            {
                // Possibly print out other members of flock as well...
                printf("l_type=%d\n", (int)flock.l_type);
            }
            close(fd);
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open '%s': %s\n", filename, strerror(errno));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The OS X file lock/immutable is a file flag (see my answer)

Comment: Regarding trojanfoe's untested code, it has now been tested :) and found to need one more line.  Before calling fcntl, you need to tell it what kind of lock you are looking for.  Typically, use
        
        flock.l_type    = F_WRLCK;
        
in which F_WRLCK says to look for either Read or Write (aka Exclusive) lock.

Answer (score 3):

If necessary, the immutable flag (OS X 'file locked') can also be determined with POSIX C functions. The immutable property is not a lock in unix terms but a file flag. It can be obtained with the `stat` function:

```
struct stat buf;
stat("my/file/path", &buf);
if (0 != (buf.st_flags & UF_IMMUTABLE)) {
     //is immutable
}
```

For reference see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/stat.2.html

The immutable flag can be set with the `chflags` function:

```
chflags("my/file/path", UF_IMMUTABLE);
```

For reference see: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/chflags.2.html